# How to get the key value inside an array to use to populate dropdown options. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I want to load the operatingSystem values as dropdown options.

```
array = [
{count: "7", operatingSystem: "MacOS X"},
{count: "2", operatingSystem: "Windows 2012"},
{count: "2", operatingSystem: "FreeBSD / MacOS X"},  
{count: "2", operatingSystem: "Linux 2.2-2.6"},
{count: "2"}];
```

Here is how I'm doing:

```
    renderFilterList(array) {
          let array2=[];
        array.map(function(obj, index) {
          Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(val) { 
            array2.push({label: val.groupBy, key: index}); 
          });
        });
// the above does not work as I'm not getting the value of the key `operatingSystem` inside in the array loop. The value `operatingSystem` is dynamic and is subject to change depending on the data I get.

//following is a internal react component im using to get the values in the dropdown
             <Dropdown
                    placeholder= "Select a value ..."
                    value={value}
                    listItems={array2}
                    key={key}
                    onSelect={this.onGroupValueSelect.bind()} />
                  </div>

    }
```

In the array2, im trying to obtain this data:

```
 const array2 = [{label: "MacOS X", key:1},
              {label: "Microsoft", key:2},
              {label: "Linux", key:3},
              {label: "Windows", key:4}];
```

how can I get the key value so that I'm able to populate the dropdown options with the values inside the array?
Any ideas?? Thanks!!

Comment: Why are using `map` and not having it return anything: that's the whole point of `map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: yes, I'll have it returned the array2, but right now, I'm stuck at populating appropriate values into the array2.

Comment: No, the call to `map` does *not* return `array2` -- how could it, there's no `return` statement inside `map`.  What you're trying to do is populate `array2` from a (superfluous) `forEach` inside the call to `map`.  Additionally, there are no commas separating the values in the `array` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your `Dropdown` component looks like but, given that array value, I will do this way,

```
<select>
     { arr.map((item, index) => <option value={item.operatingSystem}>
       {item.operatingSystem}</option>) }
 </select>
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prakashk/69z2wepo/101360/#&togetherjs=Cyz8HtmxGq

Note that if you want, you can filter your array first which does not have `operatingSystem` key.

If you have dynamic keys and always in the second index then do the following `

```
 <select>
      { arr.map((item, index) => { 
        const secondKey = Object.keys(item)[1];
        return item[secondKey]  && <option value={item[secondKey]}>
        {item[secondKey]}</option> }) }
 </select>
```

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prakashk/69z2wepo/101363/#&togetherjs=uBI1ey8mRs

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that the value "operatingSystem" is dynamic and changes depending on data I get. It could be any value, hence this may not work for me..

Comment: So is that always in the second index ?

Comment: yes, It'll always be the second one, but dynamic keys

Comment: If you really want key to be value for your dropdown, then you can replace `value={item[secondKey]}` with `value=[index+1]`

Answer (score 1):

For one you seem to have a problem with your data: the last entry has no `operatingSystem` key.  Now we could first `filter`, and then `map`, but that is sub-optimal since internally they both loop over the data, therefore resulting in two loops

If data without an `operatingSystem` key is always a possibility, your best option in my opinion is `reduce` -- it reduces the looping to just once.

```
let array2 = array.reduce((result, value, index) => {
  if (value.operatingSystem) {
    result.push({label: value.operatingSystem, key: result.length + 1})
  }
  return result;
}, []);
```

What I like about this is, rather than `forEach` (or a `for` loop), you don't separately initialize `array2 = []` and then `push` onto it; instead you assign the result of `reduce` directly to `array2`.  Notice I don't use the `index` variable, but you could write the `result.push` line as follows, and possibly get different keys if that's what you want and depending on how much data you have and how many might not have the `operatingSystem` key populated:

`result.push({label: value.operatingSystem, key: index + 1})`

If you accidentally included an entry without an `operatingSystem` key and they will actually always have that key, then simply use `map`, but not the way you did with `forEach` inside:

```
let array2 = array.map((value, index) => {return {
  label: value.operatingSystem,
  key: index + 1
}});
```